# FPDF image function give error from different extension

Tags: php, image, fpdf, file-extension

I want to show person image from MSSql `(image type column)` on pdf file with FDPDF. I am using the following code. But if image extension is png, the function gives an error.

How can I solve this problem?

```
$pic = 'data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode(pack("H*" ,preg_replace("/[^0-9a-f]+/i", "" ,$srcOBS))); 

$pdf->Image($pic, 17, 46,32.5,40,'jpg');
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: "FPDF error: Not a JPEG file: "

Comment: try changing `text/plain` to `image/png`.

Comment: Now give error from JPG images, error message : FPDF error: Not a PNG file: